# Kohana/PHP Custom exception handling not working in Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

How is it possible to replace the stock exception page(red and gray one) with the one i designed.

I followed the following steps

Step 1) Copied System/classes/Kohana/Exception.php to  Application/classes/Kohana/Exception.php and added the following snippet

```
class Kohana_Exception extends Kohana_Kohana_Exception { 


    public static function handler(Exception $e) {

       echo 'here'; die;

        switch (get_class($e)) {
            case 'HTTP_Exception_404':
                echo 'here';
                $this->HandleException(404, 'errors/404');
                return TRUE;
                break;

            default:
                return Kohana_Kohana_Exception::handler($e);
                break;
        }
    }
```

I checked the Application/bootstrap.php and ensured the presence of following code

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/web/',
        'index_file' => '',
        'errors' => true,
        'profile'       => (Kohana::$environment == Kohana::DEVELOPMENT),

));
```

I just wanted to  see the value 'here' getting displayed which i have given inside the handler method of Kohana_Exception, but the execution is never hitting that line.

I also noticed that giving  a false value to the init(errors) is not turning off the stock exception page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using outdated exception handling routines. In Kohana 3.3 one must use the method explained in the following link
http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/tutorials/error-pages